# Creating nested components taken from parent component as a props

Tags: reactjs, methods, components

I've got a theoretical problem. I've got two React components: Parent and Child. Within Parent component I'm creating some components (First, Second, Third...) and passing them to Child component as an array (arr).

```
    Parent
const First = () => {
      return <div>1st</div>;
    };
    const Second = () => {
      return <div>2nd</div>;
    };
    const Third = () => {
      return <div>3rd</div>;
    };
    const arr = [First, Second, Third];
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="Main">
            <Child arr={arr} />
          </div>
        );
    }
```

I need to invoke those passed components them by the method (nest()) in a Child component, nested one in another like this:

```
<First>
  <Second>
    <Third />
  </ Second>
</ First>
```

I can map them and get a list but have no idea how to make them nested.

As I mentioned before I managed to render them as following:

```
Child
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.nest = this.nest.bind(this);
      }
      nest() {
        return this.props.arr.map(element => <div key={element}>{element()}</div>);
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.nest()}
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Please, helmp me to invoke them nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iteration of arrays like this one works best with `reduce`, or in this case, `reduceRight`:

```
nest() {
  return this.props.arr.reduceRight(
    (children, NestedComponent) => <NestedComponent>{children}</NestedComponent>,
    null
  );
}
```

It won't work well with provided components because `First`, etc. ignore `children` prop.

They should be:

```
const First = ({ children }) => {
  return <div>1st {children}</div>;
};
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to all the nest method recursively and not map over the elements. Also you need to add `children` elements to the `First`, `Second` components

```
nest(arr) {
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            return React.createElement(arr[0], {}, this.nest(arr.slice(1)))
        }
        return null;
   }

   render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.nest(this.props.arr)}
          </div>
        );
   }
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kwj324pr1o)**